# How to add comments to my ngx-gallery image

Tags: angular, image-gallery

I have a ngx-gallery albums, each of them have images. By clicking on the image it is opening the full size. I need to add opportunity to comment to this preview or just attach any html code. How can i  do this ?

Is there any way to customize this package ?

This is my code

```
ngx-gallery (previewClose)="hideScrollBar()" (previewOpen)="hideScrollBar(true)" [options]="galleryOptions" [images]="galleryImages"></ngx-gallery
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have override a preview click to click with open new pop-up dialog

Answer (score 0):

on windows you can select your line of code and do ctrl + / and it will generate comment automatically